# using for loop to set a new array

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a csv file on world countries and their population over years.
I am using .insert() method to insert a new column called "change" which I want to include the change (in precentage) in population, for each passing year.
I am using for loop, pretty basically:

```
n=0
delta=[]
for i in range(0,11210):
    delta=df.population[n+1]/df.population[n]
    n+=1
    delta.append(i)
```

the output i receive is:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have used the variable name `delta` for your list and the result of `df.population[n+1]/df.population[n]`. Change one of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a column of your values for your dataframe by, `output['Arm Length by Height'] = output['Heights'] / output['Arm Length']`
No need for a for loop if you already have yours CSV file in a DF.

Comment: But that will not place the column where I want, rather place it in the end column of the DF, right?

Comment: It will not replace the column, just make sure you rename it.

Comment: That's not what I meant; if I do what you proposed, it will add a new column at the end of the DF. I am using .insert to place the new column where I want in the DF (to make sense).